# xsl:when with multiple test

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a problem with my layout for XSLFast 3.1.19. It uses xml data do generate a report.

I need every time when `Interpretation` shows up in the register `sum/comment`, a page break. But it is often more than just `Interpretation` in the xml text. 
Like...

```
<sum>
    <comment_lt>Interpretation: Negative experience.</comment_lt>
</sum>
```

Is there a way do say everytime when in comment_lt shows Interpretation then page break?

This is my actual code...

```
<xsl:call-template name="comment"/>
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="sum/comment_lt='Interpretation'"><fo:table break-after="page"/></xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

Best regards,
Marcel

Comment: Use either the `starts-with()` or the `contains()` function. -- P.S. You don't need `xsl::choose` for something that's either done or not; use `xsl:if` instead. -- P.P.S I don't think `xsl::choose` can be a child of `xsl:call-template`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use only xsl:if for this:

**XML:**

```
<root>
    <sum>
        <comment_lt>Interpretation: Negative experience.</comment_lt>
    </sum>
    <sum>
        <comment_lt>Negative experience.</comment_lt>
    </sum>
</root>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="sum">
        <table>
            <xsl:if test="contains(comment_lt, 'Interpretation')"><xsl:attribute name="break-after" select="'page'"/></xsl:if>
        </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Out:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <table break-after="page"/>
    <table/>
```